# Installation error visual studio 2013 in windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, installation

I'm trying to do that for 3 days. And im tired of that. So wanted to ask you guys.

There is my log file http://codepaste.net/8nxdbb

and its the screen capture of my error.

[image]

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.

Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer.

I've INSTALLED .NET 4.5 already.

Comment: You might not have high enough permissions: Error 1406.Could not write value  to key \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{432dd630-7e03-4c97-9d62-b99f52df4fc2}.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
[0A0C:09E0][2014-01-14T21:31:08]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.

Answer (score 0):

Your log says:

> Could not write value  to
>   key\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper
>   Objects{432dd630-7e03-4c97-9d62-b99f52df4fc2}.   Verify that you have
>   sufficient access to that key

Make sure your machine is properly elevated to administrator privileges, and disable all antivirus software you are running.  Cold restart your machine before making the next installation attempt.

Comment: Also make sure that ALL other programs are closed before you install

Comment: @Geezer68: A cold boot should accomplish that.

Comment: I didnt have any antivirus program. but i saw a new one. i didnt installed YAC protecter!!! it looks promotion program! Thanks robert. you save my day.